# How to remove lines which contain missing values

Tags: sed

I have a file with 46 columns (4+42) and 52 million rows like:

```
chr1 rs423246 102 120543 0 2 2 1 1 0 . . . -1 2 2 0 0 . . . . . 2 1 1 -1 -1
chr1 rs245622 104 134506 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 2 2 2 -1 -1 . . . 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 . 2
chr1 rs267845 105 124564 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
chr1 rs234579 106 125642 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 -1 -1 -1 1 0 0 2 1 0 . . . 2 . . 2 1 0
```

I would like to remove only lines which have missing value for all 42 columns. 
My missing value is "." (e.g. row 3 in the above example should remove)
How I can remove these lines using commands in Unix such as BWK SED or something else.
Thanks for any help and advise.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -Ev '\. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \. \.' yourfile
```

Comment: Wait a sec, doesn't `.` match any character here? You might want to add 42 slashes!

Answer (score 1):

Not the most readable, but hey!, its [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -ane 'print unless q|.| x 42 eq join q||, @F[4..$#F]' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>sed '/( .){26}/d' filename</strike>

**EDIT:**

Correction:

```
sed '/\( \.\)\{42\}/d' filename
```

or for a variable number of columns after the first 4:

```
sed '/^\([^ ]* \)\{4\}\(\. \)*\./d' filename
```

Comment: your command works but could you please explain why you choose 26. when I cut a 40 lines from my original files (38 lines with missing) and use your command, it only remain 1 line in output and remove others in despite I have 2 rows. please help! thanks

Comment: @Maher: I see the problem. In your example, the lines are truncated; line 3 ends in 26 dots. I overlooked your description ("4+42") in favor of the example. I will correct my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/(\.\s*){42}$/d' /file
```

or

```
sed 's/\./&/42;T;d' file
```

N.B. the most efficient is probably the first solution.

Answer (score -1):

Some `awk` verison

```
awk '{a=$0} gsub(/\./,x)!=42 {print a}' file
```

This prints all line that do not have 42 . using gsub to count them.

```
awk -F\. NF!=43 file
```

This counts number of fields using . as separator. (that's why 43 and not 42)

Comment: Both these commands will remove the line if there is a dot in any of the first three columns and one less dot in the last 42 columns...